# How to stop refreshing from increasing a session variable in a java servlet

Tags: java

So i'm keeping a count on some pictures a user can visit, i want to make sure though that if they click refresh it does not increase the number of counts for that picture. The below code is causing my server to crash, and respond back with an error code 500.

```
  HttpSession session = request.getSession() ;
    Integer counter = (Integer) session.getAttribute("counter");
    String accCount = (String) session.getAttribute("attributeKey") ;

    if (accCount == null) { // New session?
        response.sendRedirect("/techfore/WelcomePage");

        }

     if(counter == 0){


         counter = new Integer(counter.intValue() + 1);
            session.setAttribute("counter", counter);
    }
```

Comment: to test for a new session why not use https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpSession.html#isNew()

Comment: Oh awesome. I never knew about that just started a course on java servlets so i'm a bit new to this.